# Automatically markup part of NSTextView

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview

I currently have my NSTextView and I want it to automatically write a hashtag (#) in bold so it looks like this:

This is the string of my **#NSTextView**

(The text before/after and the length of the hashtag is **NOT** constant) 
how do I do that in Swift (3)?

Comment: Do some searching on how to setup an `NSAttributedString` using `NSRange` to apply styles to various parts of text.  After you've configured your string you can set the `NSTextView`'s `.attributedText` property to the string you've created.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far instead of making an early Christmas wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following. My view controller has a single property, textView that points to an NSTextView in my storyboard.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let text = "This is the string of my #NSTextView. All #hashtags should be displayed in bold."

        textView.string = text

        let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName : NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)]
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.characters.count)
        textView.textStorage?.setAttributes(attributes, range: range)

        do {

            let regexString = "#(\\w*)"
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexString, options: [])

            let matches = regex.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.characters.count))

            for match in matches {
                textView.textStorage?.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : NSFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14.0)], range: match.range)
            }

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhh...  Use UIKit?

Comment: You can do the same thing with NSTextView that I’ve done with UITextView, except you’ll go through NSTextView’s textStorage object to set text attributes.

Comment: Show us how, please.